# Is it possible to destroy firestore listeners soon if client is not connected?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

An App or reactJs app can listen for multiple firestore ReFs. We can create and remove listeners with lifecycle methods or react hooks. Such as: onDestroy(), `useEffect` -> retun, etc.
But this lifecycle methods may not execute in a lot of scenarios. Such as : User kills the browser from task manager, memory cleanup by OS, power outage etc.

I have checked a few answers on SO and made a conclusion that firestore listeners stay open for approx 30 min and charges for the read in that time. So if not cleared or removed listeners, charge occurs based on change.

**In short:** if firebase reference listener is not removed, for some uncontrollable reason, stop the listeners from firebase because we do not want the extra charge to occur for nothing.

How should I handle these scenarios?

Is there any way to specify/apply, if not connected to a client or if listeners not open on client, destroy those listeners immediately or within a certain period of time?

Comment: I don't know what is the reason and don't see a point for making this one a duplicate.  ____ Please try to understand it what it says.  ___ Here's a hint for understanding difference - Here you do not have control with your open listeners, because your app no longer exist sometimes. The linked one says, it has control over listeners but do not want an update.

Comment: Please reopen this.  __ This does not make sense to think its same, for listeners - no connection scenario(this question) vs pausing an update (linked question).